# Partition keeps getting corrupted. How to prevent or boot anyway?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, filesystem-corruption, xfs, rhel-7, auditd

I am running RHEL7, and my audit log partition randomly (not often, but often enough to annoy me) gets corrupted, preventing me from booting. How can I either prevent the partition from being corrupted, or ignore it and allow the system to continue to boot? "Sledgehammer" answers are acceptable.

Whenever the system becomes corrupted, I run a `umount`, followed by a `xfs_repair -L`, followed by a `mount`. This temporarily fixes the issue until the next time it gets corrupted.

1. Will disabling auditing via `auditd -e 2` or `systemctl disable auditd` solve this issue?
2. Is there a way to continue to boot (ignore the partition) if audit log partition is corrupted?
3. Can I just delete the partition, if I also disable auditing?
4. Can I put the partition in read-only mode?
5. Can I automatically detect a corrupted partition and repair it on boot? [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574128/repair-file-system-by-edit-the-fstab-file) seems to indicate I can have xfs_repair run on boot, but I'm not fully following the answer.

Comment: Why don't you ask this question of RH support?  Otherwise, why on earth would anyone use RedHat?